# I can't export module Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to add member.list.resolver.ts to app.module.ts and do routes.ts.

When I added it to routes.ts, it is highlighted in red next to the import {MemberListResolver} line and I have this error:

Module '"./_resolvers/member-list.resolver"' has no exported member 'MemberListResolver'.ts (2305)

I do not know too much what it is about when I added a folder and a different .ts file to it, I could easily import it, now that I added a file to the same folder but with a different name I can't do anything.

Below I am sending the program codes.

This is my member-list.resolver.ts

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';

@Injectable()
export class MemberDetailResolver implements Resolve<User[]>{
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService){}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User[]>{
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
    return this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving data');
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
        return of(null);
      })
      );
  }
}
```

My app.module ts

```
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import {JwtModule} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import {TabsModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';


// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      MemberListComponent,
      ListsComponent,
      MessagesComponent,
      MemberCardComponent,
      MemberDetailComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      FormsModule,
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      TabsModule.forRoot(),
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-shorthand
          tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
          whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
          blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
        }
      })
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider,
      AlertifyService,
      AuthGuard,
      UserService,
      MemberDetailResolver



   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

routes.ts

```
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';




export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {
        path: '',
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: 'members', component: MemberListComponent, resolve: {users: MemberListResolver}},
            {path: 'members/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent, resolve: {user: MemberDetailResolver}},
            {path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent},
            {path: 'lists', component: ListsComponent},
        ]
    },
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

Module '"./_resolvers/member-list.resolver"' has no exported member 'MemberListResolver'.

Comment: Add it to your list of providers in app.module.

Comment: I can't because I have this same error: Module '"./_resolvers/member-list.resolver"' has no exported member 'MemberListResolver'.ts(2305)"

Comment: I found a problem I did not change MemberDetailResolve to MemberListResolve in the member-list.resolve.ts file.